# How do I get index of a specific dropped element in a form element array?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this html:

```
<div class="content vertical-gradient">
    <div id="button_id0" class="button services rounded-corners trans-effect"><a class="title-text" href="index.php?services">Tjänster</a></div>
    <div id="button_id1" class="button prices rounded-corners trans-effect"><a class="title-text" href="index.php?prices">Priser</a></div>
    <div id="button_id2" class="button about-me rounded-corners trans-effect"><a class="title-text" href="index.php?aboutme">Om mig</a></div>
</div>
```

When the dom has been loaded I save text (html) from each button like this:

```
$(".button").each(function(index) {            
       //Store all texts (html) from buttons for later user with drag/drop       
       lastHtml[index] = $(this).html();            
}
```

where `lastHtml` is defined as a global array.

In some circumstances I want to change html of a button, but when I drag and drop it somewhere I want to go back to its original state. Therefore I save the texts(html) when the dom is loaded into variable lastHtml-array.

In the drop-section I retrieve the button's index by it's ID (The index number is retrieved by the elements button (useButtonId´), ex. button_id1 will return index 1, button_id2 will return index2 when dropped).

```
$( ".content").droppable({
    accept: ".button.dragme", //Must come from this dragged element
    drop: function( event, ui ) {                                                           
        //Show ordinary text for button                     
        var id = $(ui.helper).prop("id");
        var idArray = id.split("_id");                  //array of split between _id, example: [0] = button, [1] = 2                        
        var useButtonId = idArray[1]; 
        $(ui.helper).addClass("trans-effect").removeClass("dragme").removeClass("ui-draggable").html(lastHtml[useButtonId]);
    }   
}
```

**BUT what I really want is something like this:** (I want to have how many buttons I like without having to take in account the id, but I still want all the html-values to be saved when dom is loaded and restored to it's original state when a specific button is dragged and dropped).

```
<div class="content vertical-gradient">
    <div name="button[]" class="button services rounded-corners trans-effect"><a class="title-text" href="index.php?services">Tjänster</a></div>
    <div name="button[]" class="button prices rounded-corners trans-effect"><a class="title-text" href="index.php?prices">Priser</a></div>
    <div name="button[]" class="button about-me rounded-corners trans-effect"><a class="title-text" href="index.php?aboutme">Om mig</a></div>
</div>
```

I think!? I can use `index()`, but I really can't figure out how. I've tried with:

```
$(ui.helper).index())
$('.content').index(ui.helper))
```

but neither of them seems to return the correct index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easier to store the html on the element itself using `.data()`

```
var $btns=$('.button')
$btns.each(function(){
  var $btn=$(this);
  $btn.data('lastHtml', $btn.html());
});
```

`data()` is both getter and setter so to reset:

```
$(this).html( $(this).data('lasthtml') );
```

Alternatively create an attribute or data store like `btn-index` to reference your stored array

```
$btns.each(function(index) {            
       //Store all texts (html) from buttons for later user with drag/drop       
       lastHtml[index] = $(this).html(); 
       $(this).attr('btn-index',index)/* or*/.data('btn-index',index);           
});
```

If only using it within your droppable example, storing on element seems like easiest way to go

Comment: Both of your solutions are absolutely viable! Thanks a lot!!! (I think I would prefer storing data on the elements)

Comment: lots easier than parsing id strings for sure... I always look for ways to avoid doing that

Comment: I totally agree! :-) Me to, therefore I supplied you with this question ;-)

Comment: this is a bit counter intuitive to me in a way now. Have been using angular.js a lot.... and everything is stored away from the DOM. Is amazing framework. Do incredible things with very little code. but in jQuery terms..this si simplest path for situation